# Carrying hard drives in checked in luggage

Tags: air-travel, luggage, india, domestic-travel

This question is about flying within India. Can I place an internal hard drive and a [solid state drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive) inside my checked in luggage? I'll be wrap them in a bubble wrap and place them between my clothes so I'm not worried about damage.

I'm worried if their scanner would pickup something that'll prevent my luggage from being loaded.

I don't want to carry it in my carry-on luggage as it is usually jampacked.

Comment: No, that shouldn't be cause for concern. Don't wrap them up in tin foil. Concerns with having them in checked luggage are damage (especially for the hard drive), theft, and loss. Make sure your backups are up to date before travelling.

Comment: Yep, it might be easier to throw them away, as the chance of them making it without being stolen is minuscule.

Comment: @Aganju Have you got a source to back up your claim that it's likely to be stolen?

Comment: Airlines would never officially state that they have to live with their employees stealing stuff. If you google 'valuables checked baggage' there will be hundreds of pages that strongly recommend to never put anything of value in checked bags. If you don't believe it, feel free to ignore the advice and try.

Answer (score 3):

Should not be a problem. The security is trained to know these things and they won't offload your luggage because of this reason. I have personally carried hard disks in luggage several times.